# Completeness of the space $C^1([0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I already know that the space of the continuous functions $C([0,1]$ is complete with uniform metric $ d(f, g) \ = \  \parallel f - g \parallel _u$ But now I heard that the space $C^1([0,1])$ is not complete with this metric, but using the metric defined as $d(f, g) \ = \ \parallel f-g \parallel _u + \parallel f'-g' \parallel _u$ How can I show that this is true. I think I need to construct a convergent function using the Cauchy condition, but I don't know how can I do it. Please let me show a right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $C^1([0,1])$. Then, from the definition of $d(\cdot \, , \cdot)$ both $(f_n)$ and $(f'_n)$ are Cauchy in $C([0,1])$. But $C([0,1])$ is complete, so there exist $f,g \in C([0,1])$ such that $f_n \to f$ and $f'_n \to g$ uniformly. You are done if you can prove $g=f'$.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I can do last part of this proof.